# Zoom imageview without using UIScrollView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, zooming

I am using touch move method for moving image view and using pinch gesture for zoom image view. But I want to zoom image view in single touch. I am using touch began method for detecting touch point.

At that point i want to zoom image. I don't want to use scroll view because if i use scroll view for zoom image view then touch events can not perform.

Please any idea for zooming image view on touch began method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CCScaleTo` or `CCScaleBy` actions for the image when the touch is detected.

Comment: But i am not using cocos2d. I am only using UIKit and CCScaleTo and CCSCaleBy method is for cocos2d

Comment: @Leena I saw the cocos2d-iphone tag in your question. That is why i gave a cocos2d specific answer. But, in case of UIKit, you can just reset the frame for the image with the appropriate contentMode set.